# Do I need to activate a conda environment everytime on system initialization?

Tags: conda

Every time I start my system, the current active environment jumps back to '*base*'. how can I change to make *conda* environment "IntelPy3Dist2018" as my default until I deactivate it; in which case it may jump back to "base"?

[image: 0]

Comment: How are you initializing the base environment? What is your OS? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: # just 'deactivate' and it jumps back to *base*
# Windows 10 64-bit for Workstations
# I have created environments for different projects, I would like to continue working with the environment for as long as the project continues and switch back to 'base' when I am done with the project.